# CanCan is not allowing custom action/pages in Spree backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, spree

I have create a new role in Spree and limited it with CanCan to only one controller. However it does not allow access to custom actions/pages.

```
create, delete, index etc
```

The above actions are accessible, yet my 'clean' view is not.

Controller -

```
  def clean
    @handbags = Spree::Handbag.is_clean.page(params[:page]).per(50)
 end
```

AbilityDecorator -

```
  class AbilityDecorator
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user.respond_to?(:has_spree_role?) && user.has_spree_role?('technical')
        can :manage, Spree::Handbag
    end
  end
end

Spree::Ability.register_ability(AbilityDecorator)
```

Also tried  -

```
    can [:clean, :admin, :index etc..], Spree::Handbag
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by overriding collection_actions and adding the actions I needed to work -

```
  def collection_actions
[:index, :clean, :repair, :colour]
  end
```